# JS Random load order of span classes creating unwanted new row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, arrays

I have a page which has 20 pictures of team members. Our goal is to randomize the order in a truly random manner, while making sure that there are only enough rows for the amount of people on the team. So, if a row has 4 people in desktop, and we have 20 members, we should always have 5 rows.

We're finding a bug in our page, in that if you reload the page enough amount of times, [usually around 10] we get a row that has just one picture in it. We can't figure out how to fix it, and looking around the web hasn't brought any useful hints. We don't know where it's a fault of the JS, html, or css formatting.

Link to page in question: http://radcircle.com/announcements/team/Team2/

HTML + JS: https://gist.github.com/mazib/ecec2e987c8414f2416e

CSS: https://gist.github.com/mazib/e5f7fca548a4193d89d3

Any help would be greatly appreciated. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code, while being placed at the bottom of the page is not waiting for document ready.
In theory this shouldn't make a difference however I have had similar weird behaviour when doing this.
Try changing your javascript code to this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var array = $(".individuals").children().toArray();
    var i = array.length,
        j, temp;
    while (--i) {
        j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
        temp = array[i];
        array[i] = array[j];
        array[j] = temp;
    }

    $(".individuals").append(array);
});
```

Comment: I appreciate your input! It still has the same intermittent behavior unfortunately after updating it. It's quite confusing why sometimes there's a row just for one picture.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the errant behavior of  a new row was being caused by adding

```
max-width: 100%;
```

to a new subclass with the img element.
So, if you don't want new rows in a 100% fluid based grid, don't add max-width.